# oracle db "invalid table name" but works with sqllite

Tags: oracle

I have two databases, one is in a test environment and is sqllite3 and the other is an oracle db for qa/prod.  It's not my system and I am not in control of this set-up.  I wrote an SQL query that works in my test environment but failed against qa.  I'm assuming it has something to do with discrepancies between oracle and sqllite3 but I can't figure out what's going on.  thanks for the help.

here's the error and the SQL:

**OCIError: ORA-00903: invalid table name:**

```
SELECT 'agency' AS came_from,
account.name as account_name, agency.id as id,
agency.name as name,
agency.contact_name as contact_name, 
agency.contact_email as
contact_email, agency.phone_number as phone_number,
agency.account as account
FROM 'agency' LEFT OUTER JOIN account 
ON account.id ='agency'.account WHERE account in (1601)   
UNION SELECT 'advertiser' AS  came_from, 
account.name as account_name, advertiser.id as id,
advertiser.name as name, advertiser.contact_name as contact_name,
advertiser.contact_email as contact_email, 
advertiser.phone_number as phone_number,
advertiser.account as account 
FROM 'advertiser' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN account ON account.id = 'advertiser'.account 
WHERE account in (1601) AND (advertiser.workflow_state <> 'deleted'
OR advertiser.workflow_state
IS NULL)  ORDER BY name asc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'agency' and 'advertiser' are not valid table names in Oracle.

Most commonly, the tables would be named `AGENCY` and `ADVERTISER` and you could then change your `FROM` clauses to remove the single quotes.  Potentially, however, you created the tables using case-sensitive identifiers and would need to use double-quotes to refer to the table name, i.e.

```
SELECT *
  FROM "agency"
```

Even less likely, you created the tables using case sensitive identifiers and included single quotes in the table name in which case you'd need both double-quotes and single quotes but that would be exceptionally odd

```
SQL> create table "'agency'" (col1 number);

Table created.

SQL> select *
  2    from "'agency'";

no rows selected
```

If you're not sure what the name of the table is, you can query the data dictionary

```
SELECT owner, table_name
  FROM all_tables
 WHERE lower(table_name) like '%agency%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes from around the table names.